# Какие форматы принимает команда date -d в shell script?

Tags: дата, shell, format, sh

У меня есть программа которая скачивает графики из grafana для заданного промежутка времени. Там присутствует строчка типа:

```
startDateTime=$(date -d "$1 1 hour ago" +'%Y%m%dT%H%M%S')
```

Мне нужно описать в мануале как пользоваться этим скриптом и какие форматы времени можно принимать на входе. Я протестировал формат %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S. У нас в компании могут присутстовать множество различных форматов. К сожалению нин гугл, ни stackoverflow, ни даже "man" не помогли.

**Какие форматы принимает date -d?**

https://ss64.com/bash/date.html
"man" утверждает что можно принимать почти любые форматы ("can be in almost any common format"), что не очень помогает в понимании какие нельзя использовать. Например, он не принял формат Epoch Unix Time вычесленный в миллисекундах (в секундах принял).

Буду признателен любому ответу который может продвинуть меня дальше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если речь о программе *gnu/date*, то эта информация доступна, как обычно, в документации:

[Date input formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html#Date-input-formats)

---

в популярных дистрибутивах этот раздел можно посмотреть в [texinfo](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texinfo)-формате командой:

```
$ info "date input formats"
```

естественно, должна быть установлена программа для просмотра — *info* (обычно содержится в одноимённом пакете).